# Create a incremental form on the fly in jquery and when deleted replace with the next in line

Tags: jquery, increment

I've been playing about with some code for what seems like ages, I've now finally got it to work but there are 2 issues with it as far as I can work out.

Firstly, If you add multiple forms, it increments up i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc so if I create 3 forms and delete form 2 i'm left with forms 1 and 3, if I then go to add another form it will duplicate form 3 again then add 4, 5, 6 etc.

The way I would like it to work is, if you delete form 2, form 3 will replace all the 3's in the attributes and replace them with 2 effectively replacing form 2.

Secondly, Once I refresh the page, the forms are deleted, I would like it so that if the forms have a value to display.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33Ks6/

Here's the jquery:

```
// Add extra upload bars
$("#add").click(function() {
    var intId = $("#image_upload div").length + 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div id=\"upload-image-set-" + intId + "\"/>");
    var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"show_upload_image_link_" + intId + " size=\"36\" name=\"kandibox_theme_hero_options[show_upload_image_link_" + intId + "]\" value=\" <?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_1']; ?> \" />");
    var mediaButton = $(" <input id=\"show_upload_image_link_" + intId + "_button\" class=\"button upload_images\" type=\"button\" value=\"Upload Image\" />");
    // Media Upload Button 1
var custom_uploader;
mediaButton.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if (custom_uploader) {
        custom_uploader.open();
     return;
    }
    //Extend the wp.media object
    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
    title: 'Choose Image',
    button: {
        text: 'Choose Image'
    },
     multiple: false
});
//When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
    attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
    fName.val(attachment.url);
    });
    //Open the uploader dialog
    custom_uploader.open();
});
    var removeButton = $(" <input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
    removeButton.click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    fieldWrapper.append(mediaButton);
    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
    $("#image_upload").append(fieldWrapper);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
removeButton.click(function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    renameDivs();
});
```

...

```
function renameDivs() {
    $('#image_upload div').each(function (k, v) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'upload-image-set-' + (k + 1));
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33Ks6/1/)

Comment: Wow, that was quick, I so want to put this as answered but i've got one other part that is needed, if the form has a value, already display it?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. I'm happy to assist.

Comment: Basically, at the moment, when you click the 'add a field' button, it creates a new form without a value, but what I would like is, if you've created the form once and you typed in a value and save, the form will remain open?

Comment: You mean like saving form state via cookie?

Comment: I don't think so, more like via the database, basically, once you click 'add a field' it creates a form, when you click 'upload image' you'll get the url link for an image, once you save the page that url will be uploaded to the database, so far this works as it should, but when you refresh the page, the forms disappears but the value is still in the database, what I would like is, that if the database has a value for i.e. $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_2  it will automatically display the second form?

Comment: You will need to echo out a form for each value in the DB table. Then you can add `data-id="1"` for example to your div. You can then increment the div ids from there.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I wouldn't of got this far without you, I've got to questions, firstly Just checked the form and if you delete form 2, form 3's div changes to 2, but none of the inputs in the form do? Secondly here's the form I use in the html <div id="image_upload"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add a field" class="add" id="add" /> How do I echo out the form for each value in the database, i.e if the form has no value, will it still show? I'm starting to think what I want is impossible, if the form has no value, don't show, if the form has a value in the database then show